# Cannot connect with browser to an app running in Docker with gunicorn

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, gunicorn

I'm pretty new to Docker and am attempting to containerize a python webapp.
I have a conda environment for the app that I am initializing in the Dockerfile.
The app runs with gunicorn.
I cannot get the webapp to connect in a browser window.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    git \
    wget \
    g++ \
    libxext6 \
    libxrender1 \
    ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
WORKDIR /app
ADD ./dashapp.yml ./dashapp.yml


RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
    
RUN echo "Running $(conda --version)" && \
    conda init bash && \
    . /root/.bashrc && \
    conda update conda && \
    conda env create -f dashapp.yml

ADD . .

EXPOSE 8060
RUN echo "source activate dashapp" > ~/.bashrc
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "dashapp", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN gunicorn --workers=2 wsgi:server -b :8060 --daemon --capture-output --log-level debug --log-file=./gunicorn.log --timeout 90 --pid pid.txt
```

If I build the image and run it with
`docker run -it --name app_cont -d -p  8060:8060 app_img`
the container runs, I can view the gunicorn logs, but I cannot connect to the app in my browser at localhost:8060.

**However**, if I comment out the last RUN line of the Dockerfile, build, run, open a shell to the container and execute the exact same line that I commented out:

`gunicorn --workers=2 wsgi:server -b :8060 --daemon --capture-output --log-level debug --log-file=./gunicorn.log --timeout 90 --pid pid.txt`

I can now connect to the app in a browser window no problem.

`

I am following the basic recipe for running a conda environment in a docker container as outlined here: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/
(when I open a shell to the container my conda environent is activated, so this is working fine I think)

I am also able to successfully spin up a test flask app here and connect to it in my browser as outlined here: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2074

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong?
Thanks a lot

Comment: `RUN` is not the same thing as `CMD`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Selcuk. Indeed, replacing the RUN line with "CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8060  wsgi:server"  worked. Also, it seems necessary to remove the --daemon flag to make it work. Not sure why